# can't run C code when using top right button in vscode, it runs by clicking run code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw-w64

**I am learning C from w3schools and Bro Code on YouTube, wrote exactly the same code as he did but encountered the problem.**

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:1hr_in: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:1hr_in:4: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**I installed the compiler manually from winlibs because it couldn't auto install. It always crashed no matter what, so I manually installed mingw-w64.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

double A;
double B;
double C;

printf("Enter Side A: ");
scanf("%lf", &A);

printf("Enter Side B: ");
`scanf("%lf", &B);
`
C = sqrt(A*A + B*B);

`printf("Side C: %lf", C);`


    return 0;
}
```

**this is my code which seems to be accurate after watching it for hours and matching it to the tutorial.
when I select all of this code and click on run code it runs smoothly, but when I use the top right run button it doesn't. I'm confused**

Comment: awaiting any response

Comment: Looks like your file isn't named correctly. It must have the `.c` extension, while yours is `1hr_in` without any extension.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: problem solved, as @HolyBlackCat highlighted I forgot to add the .c extension mistakenly. rookie mistake. thanks alot for your response.